# How to write Vue js code in separate file and include in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vue.js

How to write Vue js code in separate file and include in laravel
Blade page code?

Am also using gulp file.

```
@section('js')
<script>
   new Vue({

        // Defining a element.
        el: '#branddashboard-html',

        data: {

            // Defining data variable.
            brandStats: null
        },

        // On load functionality.
        created: function () {

            // Initializing method.
            this.getData();

        },


        },

        // Methods to implement.
        methods: {

            getData: function () {

                self.brandStats = null;

                $.get('brand-stats/' + userId + '/' + period, function (data) {
                    self.brandStats = data;

                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think** this is no the best idea. I think, the Blade's Templates only works in the views folder. Your frontend logic is now managed with Vue Component System, in this MVVM vue way. Hope this be usefull to you